# NullPointer Exception when calling a method from onResume

Tags: android

I am setting my selectDate on longPress but why does it say that my selectDate is null in HighlightCalander function? Any ideas.

**This eventHandler is called in onCreate (Main Activity):-**

```
calendarview.setEventHandler(new CalendarView.EventHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDayLongPress(Date date)
            {
                DateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();
                selectDate = date;
                System.out.println(selectDate);
                intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MakeAppointmentsActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("DATE",df.format(date));
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
```

**This function is called in onResume (Main Activity):-**

```
public void HighlightCalendar()
    {
        intent2 = getIntent();
        // get my boolean from save button
        boolean savedDate = intent2.getBooleanExtra("savedDate", false);
        // if i pressed my saved button
        if(savedDate) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                DateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
                String dateString = df.format(selectDate);
                Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateString);
                events.add(dateObj);
                calendarview.updateCalendar(events);
            }catch (ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Passing `DATE `  instead of `savedDate ` also get String from Intent instead of `bool` because `df.format(date) ` return String

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to `selectDate` in `onDayLongPress` but you are using it in `onResume`. Everytime you create an `Activity` `onCreate()` and `onResume()` are called. You are getting a `NUllpointerException` because, in `onResume()` (which is called before `onDayLongPress`) `selectDate` is not initalized and therefore `null`. You could initalize `selectDate` in one of the 2 methods to avoid the exception.